# Escape comma in CSV

Tags: objective-c, csv

A one line question :
How do I escape comma so that text does not split in `CSV` ? I am asking this specific to `Objective-C`.

Comment: What library or API function are you using to *parse* the CSV?

Comment: @Pekka웃 : I am not using any library/API for this. Simply saving the file as .CSV.

Comment: Assuming the field delimiter is the comma, you need to put the value in quotes. Nothing about this question is specific to Objective-C.

Answer (score 4):

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180

> 5:  Each field may or may not be enclosed in double quotes (however
> some programs, such as Microsoft Excel, do not use double quotes
> at all).  If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then
> double quotes may not appear inside the fields.  For example:
>
> ```
> "aaa","bbb","ccc" CRLF
> zzz,yyy,xxx
> ```

> 6:  Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas
> should be enclosed in double-quotes.  For example:
>
> ```
> "aaa","b CRLF
> bb","ccc" CRLF
> zzz,yyy,xxx
> ```

> 7:  If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
> appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
> another double quote.  For example:
>
> ```
> "aaa","b""bb","ccc"
> ```

Therefore you should enclose the values containing a `,` in `"`.

```
abc,"my value, with comma",def
```